# Is it a Three.js bug?

Tags: html5-canvas, shadow, three.js

I found a great three.js demo here: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_geometry_earth.html

I noticed, that there are some line in the shadow of the earth. Is it a bug, or the author made it by design?

Comment: It is by design, which I believe is to get a sense of the perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That lines are there because geometry used for shadow has an `overdraw: true` parameter.

That parameter is used to hide some anti-alias gaps using `CanvasRenderer`. It works fine for opaque textures, like the earth one, but not for transparent textures, like the shadow, because the "overdrawing" effect.

Remove parameter, or change it to `false`, and you can see the difference.